# How to work with FileProvider and EncryptedFile?

Tags: android, file, encryption, android-fileprovider

I want to store files in a secure way for a small period of time, to be able to share the file using FileProvider, because it is sensitive data we want to encrypt the file and just decrypt it on sharing.

I was using this code to encrypt and decrypt the file:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography

But I am not sure what kind of modifications I should do in the standard implementation of a FileProvider to provide a copy of an encrypted file.

Comment: `and just decrypt it on sharing.` Ok. Decrypt on sharing. `to provide a copy of an encrypted file.`  ?? Now you wanna server the encrypted file? It is unclear what you really want.

Comment: It seems to be too late to change anything after you've shared the URL, so I suppose you'll have to do it when [sharing the URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#ServeUri). It depends then where you generate the URL to perform the decryption.

Comment: The way I understand it an unencrypted file should be provided via the FileProvider. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035057/work-with-encrypted-file-and-provide-them-with-fileprovider/)